# CSS - Hide button by its value

Tags: html, css

How to hide button by its value using CSS ?

eg:

```
<input type="submit" value="Foo" />
<input type="submit" value="Bar" />
```

How i can hide the Button that have `value="Foo"`

Comment: `input[value="Foo"]{display:none;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/WpzYLR

```
input[value="Foo"]{
  display:none;
}
```

using this method above

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with  css attribute selectors:

```
input[value="Foo"] { 
    display:none;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update style**   More learn [**css attribute selectors**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

```
input[value="Foo"] { 
    display:none;
}
```

```css
input[value="Foo"] { 
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Foo" />
<input type="submit" value="Bar" />
```